# AMPscript IF Statement returning variable as empty

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am running into an issue in AMPscript where the following IF statement is returning my variable @shippingVendor as nothing when I call it. (Tracking Number is from data extension)

Assuming @trackingNumber = 23456

```ampscript
%%[
var @shippingVendor

IF Substring(@trackingNumber, 1, 1) == "2" THEN
   SET @shippingVendor = "https://www.nzpost.co.nz/tools/tracking/item/"
  ELSEIF Substring(@trackingNumber, 1, 2) == "T1" THEN
   SET @shippingVendor = "https://www.mainfreight.com/en-nz/tracking?trackingnumber="
  ELSEIF Substring(@trackingNumber, 1, 3) == "TP1" THEN
   SET @shippingVendor = "https://www.mytoll.com/?"
ENDIF
]%%
```

I would expect `%%=v(@shippingVendor)=%%` to return `https://www.nzpost.co.nz/tools/tracking/item/` - however instead it returns nothing...can I please check if I am doing anything wrong?

Fairly new to AMPscript so would love your help on this - thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [marketing-cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) and [ampscript](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ampscript) tags.

Answer (score 1):

It's dangerous to do substring in AMPscript without checking for existence and length.  I'd also set a default value for the shipping vendor URL.

```ampscript
%%[

set @trackingNumber = 23456

set @shippingVendor = "DEFAULVENDORURLHERE"

if not empty(@trackingNumber) then

   IF length(@trackingNumber) >= 1 and Substring(@trackingNumber, 1, 1) == "2" THEN

      SET @shippingVendor = "https://www.nzpost.co.nz/tools/tracking/item/"

   ELSEIF length(@trackingNumber) >= 2 and Substring(@trackingNumber, 1, 2) == "T1" THEN

      SET @shippingVendor = "https://www.mainfreight.com/en-nz/tracking?trackingnumber="

   ELSEIF length(@trackingNumber) >= 3 and Substring(@trackingNumber, 1, 3) == "TP1" THEN

      SET @shippingVendor = "https://www.mytoll.com/?"
      
   ENDIF

endif

]%%
shippingVendor: %%=v(@shippingVendor)=%%
```

Output:

```
shippingVendor: https://www.nzpost.co.nz/tools/tracking/item/
```

Demo: https://mcsnippets.herokuapp.com/s/eiSqyIcb